# Лог данных попавших в jsp страницу из java бэкенда

Tags: java, jsp, frontend

Здравствуйте, есть интересный вопрос, на который я нигде не нашел ответа.
Например, я занимаюсь фронт-эндом, моя задача верстать страницы писать js и css.
Т.к. бэк-энд на java, фронт делается с помощью jsp.

Я столкнулся с такими неудобствами, что когда мне нужно узнать какие переменные попадают в текущую jsp, например нужны св-ва какого-то объекта, мне нужно копаться в (в бэк-энде) чтоб узнать это. Это супер неудобно. Есть ли возможность узнать, что попало в текущую jsp без копания в java классах.

Может что-то вроде `var_dump` в php, или `console.log()` в js?

Comment: Можно вывести содержимое объекта request на экран или в фаил

Comment: Как его вывести на экран?

Comment: 1) получить мапу параметров  с помощью `request.getParameterMap()`  
 2) вывести ее на экран     
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287317/displaying-hashmap-key-value-in-jsp-display-table

Comment: Вот сделал:
<% Map map = request.getParameterMap(); %>
 <c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
        Key = ${entry.key}, value = ${entry.value}<br>
</c:forEach>
Не работает, вообще ничего не выводит

Comment: попробуйте так 
` <%
        Map<String, String[]> map = request.getParameterMap();    
        for (String s : map.keySet()) {
            String f = "";
            f = s+" : "+map.get(s)[0];


    %>
    <%= f %>
    <%
        }
    %>`

Comment: результат - тоже пустота